# Create distinct sets from given list of integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, subset

How can I create a function to generate distinct sets bases on give values?

here we have input list: `[4, 5, 6]`

output should be like this:

```
output = [[],[6],[5],[6,5],[6,4],[5,4],[5,6],[4,5],[4,6],[4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
l = [4,5,6]

n = len(l)
r = []

for i in range(pow(2,n)):
    t = []
    for j in range(n):
        k = (str(bin(i))[2:]).zfill(3)[j]
        #print(k)
        if k == '1':
            t.append(l[j])
    r.append(t)
print(r)
```

Comment: Any explanation why the negative vote?!?

Comment: 1. Don't answer obvious dupes.  2. Don't reinvent the wheel  3. Using the string domain is bizarre

Comment: Is it a good way just vote down?